# Backbone.js Event Binding

Tags: jquery, events, binding, callback, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js have a segmented control-type UI element for each model's view. They are each made up of a ul with a few li elements. I want to bind an event such that when one of these elements is clicked, I can determine which one has been clicked and update the model with the appropriate value.

The problem is that Backbone binds the events (these are in the events hash of the view) such that "this" in the callback function refers to the view, not the li elements. This means that I can not determine which of the several li elements has been clicked. If I used a normal jQuery binding, I can have "this" bound to the li elements, but then I don't have track of the model anymore, so I can't update it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

jQuery's habit of setting `this` to whatever happens to be convenient at the time is a pretty nasty pattern, in my opinion -- fortunately, you never have to rely on it:

```
onClick: function(e) {
  this;                // Still the view instance (as it should be).
  e.target;            // The element that was clicked.
  e.currentTarget;     // The element that was bound by the click event.
}
```

... You can use the `target` or `currentTarget` of the event object, as appropriate.

Comment: That, and, Internet Explorer has a nasty habit of interpreting `this` as `window` if your scope's not clean.

Comment: This only works for jquery-triggered events, right? Events triggered through backbone's trigger() function will not pass on a jquery event, but instead the arguments you entered into trigger()

Comment: @JensAlm That's right. Backbone's .trigger() function triggers events on Backbone models, whereas the Backbone views 'event' list is hooked up to jQuery's delegateEvents. They are two different event systems.

Answer (score 20):

Can't figure out why I can't comment on @jashkenas answer above. His method is correct (thank you!) but I thought I'd clarify the situation: in your event handler, you can recover the element that the event was bound to. Sample backbone code would look like this:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .item': 'handleClick'
    },

    handleClick: function(e) {
        this; // The view instance
        e.target; // The element that was clicked 
        e.currentTarget; // The element that was bound by the click event
    }
});
```

I use this to setup default text in all of my form fields...yeah I'm not much into HTML5 yet :)

**Edit:**
Btw, e.target is the raw element. You'll need to use $(e.target) to get jQuery access.

Comment: This is the way to go if you are using backbone.

Comment: Still seems lame that you have to know that have to know the CSS class of what's being clicked. Something like `'click this.$el': 'handleClick'` would be preferable.

Comment: It is not lame, as you may have different behaviours assigned to elements contained in your object's view (ex. one link for editing, another one for deleting, placed right by your item's title, this title leading you to the show view when clicked). Or am I wrong thinking that ?