# Backbone.js Reverse Binding (UI to Model)

Tags: forms, events, binding, backbone.js

I trying to generate forms with Backbone.js,

Here is how I am doing it now.

Each Input element on the form has a `Model` and a `View`. So as usual the `model` contains attributes like `type` `value` `name` `placeholder` etc .

By backbone convention I have gotten changes to `Model` reflecting on the `UI`

But I want the reverse also to happen,
that is when the `value` of an `input` element changes that has to reflect upon the model's attribute `value`.

Here is where I am right now: 
[prototype1.js](https://github.com/gautamk/backbone.js-Learning/blob/1de35c0ead79a0fac229d5f31d9ddd5e6d5f8c26/js/prototype1.js)

I am thinking of writing a update method on the view which will update the model, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5273224/492561). Is there a better way to do it ?

PS :

This has not helped much [stackoverflow search: backbone.js reverse model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=backbone.js%20reverse%20model%20binding)

Any general advice is also welcome along with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever heard of [backbone.modelbinding](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding)?
it's a plugin created by Derick Bailey, that was brought to live especially for that purpose,

once a model changes, it updates the view,
once the view changes it updates the model.

i've used it before, and it works very well for a straight forward form,
as for now i don't see why it wouldn't work with your form,
but you'd have to try it out and see whether your structure fits.

initializing is quite easy:

```
SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function(){
    // ... render your form here
    $(this.el).html("... some html and content goes here ... ");

    // execute the model bindings
    Backbone.ModelBinding.bind(this);
  }
});
```

that is the basic straightforward binding,
you can go mutch further than that:

you can bind model to view that does not render (already in the page)
you can bind to multiple model properties
you can do binding through data-bind style attributes in the form if you would want that
you can bind to a model's events

lot's of options, so take a look at it and see if it fit's your app.

Comment: Backbone.ModelBinding has been abandoned because it was terrible.

Comment: I haven't developed in backbone in the past half year, was not aware of that, however did any alternative pop up after modelbinding being abandoned?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem having a `View` that updates the `Model`'s state. Actually I think this is a very proper way to work due the `View` is in charge of manage the **User interactions** and usually the result of a User interaction is modify the state of a Model.

Said that I'd propose:

1. Use the [events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) View property to bind *changes* on the DOM elements of your view.
2. Declare methods on your View that are called when the event occur and **modify the state of the model** into this methods.