# Using current jQuery element in backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Am slowing get a hang of backbone.js, but i've run into a bit of bind.
I've successfully created a view, and am able to delegate events to element in the DOM, however i can seem to be able to use the jQuery "`$(this)`" in the following context

```
Chrono.Views.Sidebar = Backbone.View.extend({
    //Page wrapper
    el:"#wrapper",

    //Delegate events to elements
    events : {
        "click .push-to":"loadPage"
    },
    loadPage: function(event) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        alert(url);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The click event is intercept but this line "var url = $(this).attr("href");"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of `loadPage`, `this` has been bound to your `Chrono.Views.Sidebar` instance.  However, you can get the DOM element that the event was triggered on through `event.currentTarget`.  If you update your function to look like this it should work:

```
loadPage: function(event) {
    var url = $(event.currentTarget).attr("href");
    alert(url);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In backbone this is bound to the view, but you can still get the element that was clicked by checking the event.target or the element that the event was bound to using event.currentTarget.

Take a look at this question
[Backbone.js Event Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270188/backbone-js-event-binding)

Answer (score 0):

`this` is bound to the view, so you can access the `View.$el` property directly.

```
loadPage: function(event) {
    var url = this.$el.find('.push-to').attr('href');
    alert(url);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```