# this that pass inside object as parameter to Backbone View : "window" or "backbone view" object?

Tags: backbone.js

The code:

```
var Appointment = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var appointment = new Appointment();
appointment.set('title', 'My knee hurts');
var AppointmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html('<li>' + this.model.get('title') + '</li>');
  }
});
```

Question about that: $(this.el)... 
looks like "this" is "window" object and not event object?

Please if you can expain deeply how it working.

Thanks,
Yosef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In backbone.js views the `this` is bound to the view object, not the window. You can access the event object if needed and through there get a reference to the target element. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270188/backbone-js-event-binding) for some more information.

Comment: Can you explain please how it done? How backbone takes this == window  and make it this == backbone event?

Comment: Thanks,Can you please show the place in the code of backbone that recognize this as view object?

Comment: @Yosef: Do you mean [this part of `delegateEvents`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1258)?

Comment: I haven't really looked that closely, but I think its in the method delegateEvents starting on line `1224`, more specifically line 1233 `method = _.bind(method,this)` (`_bind` is an underscore.js method).