# backbone + binding

Tags: json, backbone.js

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('hello'),
events: {                           
      'click .myName':  'namefunc',
},   
initialize: function() {
    var stuff = new FieldCollection();
    stuff.parse();
    var self = this;
    stuff.fetch({
        success: function (collection, response) {
            console.log(response);
            self.render(response);
            return response;
        }
    });
},
render:function(output){
    _.each(output, function(i){
        p=i.name;
        $(this.el).append("<button class='myName'>"+p+"</button><h1>"+i.img+"</h1><br/>");
    },this);     

},
namefunc:function(){
    alert('hiii');
}
```

how to bind the change the hiii output of alert with the details of the person against whom the button is pressed...

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "img": "john.jpg",
    "loc": "delhi",
    "msg": "hello there"
}
```

this is the json which i m getting....when i click on button(having john name) it should show its msg....

Comment: Can you explain the issue better?

Comment: Check out this [post][1]. All you need


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270188/backbone-js-event-binding

Comment: @schacki that post is not what i m looking for

Comment: I think there is not only one thing you should fix here. For example you are managing all the elements event through the `LisView` instead of using `SubViews` for element. You are sending the `fetch()` response directly to `render()` instead of using a proper Backbone Collection, ... so it is difficult to come with a simple answer here.. try to organiza a little better all this.

Comment: then please explain in more detail what is the problem, what would you like to happen and what happens instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initialize: function() {
var self = this;
_.bindAll(this, 'render');
this.collection = new FieldCollection();
this.collection.parse();

this.collection.fetch({
    success: function (collection, response) {
        console.log(response);
        self.render();
    }
});
```

},

```
render:function(){
var self = this;
_.each(this.collection, function(model) {
    // here you should create subviews and delegate events within particular view
    // i.e:
    // self.buttonViews.push(new ButtonView({ model: model}));
    // but for now you can use data-id attribute to match the button you clicked
    $(self.el).append("<button class='myName' data-id=" + model.id + ">" + model.name + "</button><h1>" + model.img + "</h1><br/>");
});
```

},

```
namefunc:function(){
//use data-id attribute we put in button tag earlier to catch the id
//and use this.collection.get('id') function to get the model you want to get parameters of
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If i've understood your question, you could just do something like...

```
var _self = this, 
    obj = Object;

$("<button>"+someVariable+"</button>")
    .addClass('myName')
    .appendTo(this.$el)
    .on({
        "click": function() { _self.fn(obj) }
    });
```

​

Comment: also, in backbone you have a jquery object for this.el automatically in this.$el so you don't need to $(this.el)